# Как узнать какой стиль перекрывает другой в css?

Tags: css

Не применяется медиа запрос css из-за перекрытия другим стилем, можно ли как-то узнать каким?

Comment: С помощью испектора элементов в браузере (F12). Смотрите какой стильперекрывает ваш

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В браузере в панели разработчика  строки стилей, там печеркиваются селекоторы, а выше перечеркнутого тот селектор, который оказал влияние [image: введите сюда описание изображения]